# What programming language is this? echo os.system('/bin/bash')

Tags: python, shell, tty

I found it here: https://netsec.ws/?p=337

```
echo os.system('/bin/bash')
```

os.system is from python but echo is not, I think... what language is this exactly?

Comment: It's a *pen testing list*; presumably the `echo` is piped to something that the tester hopes will run the code.

Comment: In other words, it's just one part, coded in `sh`, where the echoed result is to be executed by something else, perhaps the current shell implementation.

Comment: Yeah, that is a shell script to see if  whatever it's hooked up to is talking to a Python interpreter that will execute the `os.system()` bit.

Comment: It can't be a shell script - at least not bash/dash/zsh - because of the parentheses. You would get a syntax error.

Comment: It's a shell script because of the `echo`. The `echo` sends a Python command to whatever `stdout` is connected to, hoping it's a Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked at the echo tag, you'll see its description: *"Simple function outputting text. Exists in script languages."*, if you're running Linux or Mac and even Windows Command Prompt you can enter this:

```
$ echo Hello shell world
```

Output:

```
Hello shell world
```

`echo` is useful for testing shell glob expansion, echoing the values of environment variables and sending output to stdins of other programs, for example try this with Bash:

```
$ echo 'print("Spam" * 2)' | python -
```

Output:

```
SpamSpam
```

And this:

```
$ echo 'import os; os.system("echo SPAM")' | python -
```

Output:

```
SPAM
```